How do you implement diamond proxy fallback function?
According to the official EIP2535 in the fallback section:
It is missing the position slot:
// Find facet for function that is called and execute the
// function if a facet is found and return any value.
fallback() external payable {
  // get facet from function selector
  address facet = selectorTofacet[msg.sig];
  require(facet != address(0));
  // Execute external function from facet using delegatecall and return any value.
  assembly {
    // copy function selector and any arguments
    calldatacopy(0, 0, calldatasize())
    // execute function call using the facet
    let result := delegatecall(gas(), facet, 0, calldatasize(), 0, 0)
    // get any return value
    returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())
    // return any return value or error back to the caller
    switch result
      case 0 {revert(0, returndatasize())}
      default {return (0, returndatasize())}
  }
}

However, when in the reference implementation you can download and open up EIP2535-Diamonds-Reference-Implementation.zip in the proposal it include the storage position:
    // Find facet for function that is called and execute the
    // function if a facet is found and return any value.
    fallback() external payable {
        LibDiamond.DiamondStorage storage ds;
        bytes32 position = LibDiamond.DIAMOND_STORAGE_POSITION;
        // get diamond storage
        assembly {
            ds.slot := position
        }
        // get facet from function selector
        address facet = ds.facetAddressAndSelectorPosition[msg.sig].facetAddress;
        if(facet == address(0)) {
            revert FunctionNotFound(msg.sig);
        }
        // Execute external function from facet using delegatecall and return any value.
        assembly {
            // copy function selector and any arguments
            calldatacopy(0, 0, calldatasize())
             // execute function call using the facet
            let result := delegatecall(gas(), facet, 0, calldatasize(), 0, 0)
            // get any return value
            returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())
            // return any return value or error back to the caller
            switch result
                case 0 {
                    revert(0, returndatasize())
                }
                default {
                    return(0, returndatasize())
                }
        }
    }


Apparently there is a default storage slot but not sure why that fallback section is not utilizing it:
    function diamondStorage() internal pure returns (DiamondStorage storage ds) {
        bytes32 position = DIAMOND_STORAGE_POSITION;
        assembly {
            ds.slot := position
        }
    }

